# Navigating to a tree of directories and get the path for each file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm navigating over the directories using:

```
  for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(base_dir):
        for fname in fileList:
            file_path = os.path.join(dirName, *subdirList, fname)
```

The `file_path` is incorrect because it adds all subdirectories, and what I want is to get the full
path to the file.

Comment: just `os.path.join(dirName, fname)`

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk` is a little hard to grasp at first. In:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(base_dir):
```

`dirName` *follows* the current `subdirList` and `fileList`. At each iteration, the triplet is updated with the list of files & directories for each `dirName`.

So you must not mix directory list and file list. Just do

```
file_path = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
```

As a side note, if you don't need the directories, you can "mute" the directory list:

```
for dirName, _, fileList in os.walk(base_dir):
```